# C++ alternatives to std::array when the size is fixed, but not a constexpr?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What is the best replacement for `std::array<...>` if I don't want to have to provide constexpr size? I figured it would be best to just use `std::vector` and do `reserve(...)` on it, but maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: There was a proposal for a fixed size [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray). Unfortunately it didn't make it into C++14.

Comment: Why did the Committee decide not to accept it? I see it is in experimental, meaning it probably still stands a chance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use `std::vector`.

So if your code is

```
std:array<int, 42> my_array;
```

Replace it by

```
std:vector<int> my_array(42);
```

Note: you probably don't want to use `reserve`, because it leaves the `vector` empty. If you are using `std::array`, your code doesn't have the concept of empty array, so it's best represented by a `std::vector` instance that is filled at construction, and never resized.

Comment: With a `std::vector<int>`, I might use `resize(42)` instead of specifying an initial capacity. With `my_array(42)`, I'd be worried about people thinking `42` is an initial element, or even changing it to `my_array{42}` and silently breaking things.

Comment: A small problem with this is that it fills the vector with zeros, while the declaration of array in your example leaves it uninitialized. This can matter if the vector is expected to have large size.

Answer (score 17):

`std::vector` should be the correct container of choice, if the size needs to be determined at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector<>` is probably your answer. I just wouldn't assume `reserve()` guarantees any speedup.

Bjarne Stroustrup:

> People sometimes worry about the cost of std::vector growing
>   incrementally. I used to worry about that and used reserve() to
>   optimize the growth. After measuring my code and repeatedly having
>   trouble finding the performance benefits of reserve() in real
>   programs, I stopped using it except where it is needed to avoid
>   iterator invalidation (a rare case in my code). Again: measure before
>   you optimize.

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html [See bottom of "Why are the standard containers so slow?"]

Comment: I'd say that in most cases calling `reserve` is not so much about guaranteeing speedup (which would mean as much as that STL "guarantees slowdown" when omitting the call), but about choosing the shorter solution when it is simple and obvious. Often you know at allocation time exactly how large your vector will become, even if for some reason you cannot construct it to that size but need repeated `push_back` to fill it. Then not calling `reserve` would be as silly as not breaking out of a linear search when a match is found; sure the speedup might be small, but the improvement  is obvious.